# Find missing values in an alphanumeric sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to identify missing values in an alphanumeric sequence.

The table is defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `seqtest` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PoleNo` text,
  `Pre` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Num` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The data is as shown below and will always be one letter (A-Z) followed by three numbers from 000 to 999.

```
| PoleNo |  Pre  |  Num  |
|------------------------|
| A000   |   A   |  000  |
| A001   |   A   |  001  |
| A002   |   A   |  002  |
| A004   |   A   |  003  |
| ****   |   *   |  ***  |
| A998   |   A   |  998  |
| A999   |   A   |  999  |
| B000   |   B   |  000  |
| B001   |   B   |  001  |
| B002   |   B   |  002  |
| ****   |   *   |  ***  |
| B998   |   B   |  998  |
| B999   |   B   |  999  |
| C000   |   C   |  000  |
| C001   |   C   |  001  |
| C005   |   C   |  005  |
| C006   |   C   |  006  |
|------------------------|
```

I want the query to find that, for example,  C002, C003 AND C004 are missing as shown below.

```
|  Pre  | start | stop |
|   C   |   2   |   4  |
|----------------------|
```

Im using the following:

```
SELECT l.Pre, l.Num + 1 as start, min(fr.Num) - 1 as stop
FROM seqtest as l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN seqtest as r ON l.Num = r.Num - 1 AND l.Pre = r.Pre
    LEFT OUTER JOIN seqtest as fr ON l.Num < fr.Num AND l.Pre = fr.Pre
WHERE r.Num is null AND l.Num < 999
GROUP BY l.Pre, l.Num, r.Num
```

which is based on [this](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/06/find-missing-numbers-in-a-sequence-with-sql).

It gives me the range that is missing and works well except for one case...when 'Pre' changes from one letter to the next.

IE With the following data:

```
| PoleNo |  Pre  |  Num  |
|------------------------|
| B995   |   B   |  995  |
| B996   |   B   |  996  |
| B997   |   B   |  997  |
| C003   |   C   |  003  |
| C004   |   C   |  004  |
| C005   |   C   |  005  |
| C006   |   C   |  006  |
|------------------------|
```

Id like to be able to return this:

```
|  Pre  | start | stop |
|   B   |  998  |  999 |
|   C   |   0   |   2  |
|----------------------|
```

Is this possible? Im using the `Pre` and `Num` fields which are simply the `PoleNo` field broken up...but if anyone sees a way to do it just using the `PoleNo` field, that would work as well.

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.5.14

Comment: Can you setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ Real data would help in trying to fine tune the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier in MySQL 8+, because you have `lead()`.  But, you can do what you want as:

```
select st.pre,
       (st.num + 1) as start,
       (st.next_num - 1) as stop
from (select st.*,
             (select st2.num
              from seqtest st2
              where st2.pre = st.pre and
                    st2.num > st.num
              order by st2.num asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_num
      from seqtest st
     ) st
where next_num <> num + 1;
```

EDIT:

This gets the ranges at the beginning and end as well:

```
select st.pre, 
       (st.num + 1) as start,
       (st.next_num - 1) as stop
from (select st.pre, num,
             coalesce( (select st2.num
                        from seqtest st2
                        where st2.pre = st.pre and
                              st2.num > st.num
                        order by st2.num asc
                        limit 1), 1000
                      ) as next_num
      from seqtest st
      union
      select st.pre, 0 as num, min(st.num) as next_num
      from seqtest st
      group by st.pre
     ) st
where next_num <> num + 1
order by pre, start;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3239a255e5a2aae0ab1dbfe34c4a9497) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Im sorry, but that does not work. My database contains 5935 records. Of them, A010, A011, B999, C000 and C001 are missing. The query you posted returns 5923 records. My query above returns A010, A011 and B999...Im only missing the C000 and C001.

Comment: @JonHenry . . . Try it now.  It comes much closer.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the query I originally posted already does that plus gets the B998. I just cant find a way to get the next C000 and C001 with it.